# Generated Protobuf objc .m file has incorrect #import

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers, proto

I've tried to generate objc protofiles for each subfolder from root:

```
protoc */*.proto --objc_out="../result"  -I.
```

[image]

Example proto:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message MyProtoType {
    required string myProtoName = 1;
}
```

And `protoc` successfully generates objc files, but .m file contains not correct `#import`

```
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: MyFolder/MyProto.proto

...

#import "MyFolder/MyProto.pbobjc.h"
// @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

...
```

Somebody can explain how to generate correct import, without running `protoc` in each subfolder `protoc *.proto --objc_out="../result"  -I.` with a script that loops through them?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the generated code. If you want to generate `#import` statements without any path and do not mind if the output files are at the root directory instead of the location of the .proto file, add the folder to the protoc search directories with `--proto_path`.

```
protoc */*.proto --objc_out=. --proto_path MyFolder
```